# jQuery tree view within a form in ZF

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, view, tree

in Zend Framework I need to create a form with a tree view. The tree view must have checkboxes so the different nodes can be checked.

What is the best way to do this? Any help will be appreciated and any example or tutorial will be the cherry on the cake ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the clearest example (step by step) on how to build up your html around your zend form elements: http://devzone.zend.com/article/3450

You basically need to mix your Zend form elements up with your html.

Tree View Example: http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/

Zend mixing form elements with html can be acheived using zend form decorators: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.decorators.html

Hope this helps :) Good luck by the way Zend is always a bit of a pain for things like this :)

Comment: Yes indeed, this is just pain ;) I found some help in this thread http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=69&t=5171#p17805 but I still have to implement it. Will come back when I success... :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out here http://paveldubinin.com/2011/04/custom-zend-element-checkbox-tree/
There's a ready-made Zend Element for that with description and usage examples.